# C Struct Compile Error

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

Why does the following code produce a compile-time error? I cannot seem to see why the types are mismatched.

```
typedef char f_string[MAX_CHARS+1] ;    /* string for each field */

/*
 * A parsed CSV line, with the number of fields and upto MAX_FIELDS themselves.
*/

typedef struct {
    int nfields ;               /* 0 => end of file */
    f_string field[MAX_FIELDS] ;        /* array of strings for fields */
} csv_line;

....

csv_line sut;
sut.field[0] = "Name, "; //Compile-time error.
```

Error being:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sut.field[0]` is a `char[MAX_CHARS+1]`

`"Name, "` is a `const char*`

Try this:

```
strcpy(sut.field[0], "Name, ");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Acceptance for this answer because it was the quickest, kind of hard to choose between the others.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign a `const char *` to a `char[]`, which is not quite the same thing. This would work if your `f_string` were defined as

```
typedef const char * f_string;
```

What you are looking for here is

```
strcpy ( sut.field[0], "Name, " );
```

Or use `strncpy` so that you can specify the size of the destination buffer ..

```
strncpy ( sut.field[0], "Name, ", MAX_CHARS )
```

That will keep you from overrunning your buffer.

Comment: `strncpy()` is *not* a "safe `strcpy`" - it is intended for handling fixed-length string fields, which do not necessarily have a null-terminator.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "safe `strcpy`". `strncpy` allows you to limit the number of characters copied to the destination buffer. If you set the max number of characters to something less than the size of the destination buffer, you will not overrun it if the source buffer contains a string larger than the destination buffer can hold. What will happen, as I have been reminded, is that you will not have a terminating null in your destination buffer; that case will have to be handled and the null added.

Comment: Right: it does not add a terminating `'\0'` if the source string is too long; and if the source string is short, it fills the remainder of the destination (which may be quite large) with `'\0'`.  Since the former has to be handled, it is not the "drop in" replacement for `strcpy()` that many seem to believe.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use something like:

```
strcpy( sut.field[0],"Name, ");
```

You can't assign strings like you tried other except as an initializater at declaration time.

Answer (score 2):

the type of sut.field[0] is array-of-char of size MAX_CHARS+1 - you cannot assign a string pointer to an array of characters.

You'd either need to change the type of csv_line::field to a const char*, or just do a string copy of the literal "Name, " to the target array.

Note that both `strcpy()` and `strncpy()` alone are unsafe: the first might overflow your buffer, and the second might leave it without a NUL terminator. You must be aware of BOTH of these circumstances even if you "know" that your string in question won't ever overflow.

Use a helper function to do this safely:

```
char * strncopy(char *dst, const char *src, int dstsize)
{
    strncpy(dst, src, dstsize-1);
    dst[dstsize-1] = '\0';

    return dst;
}
```

Then:

```
strncopy(sut.field[0], "Name, ", sizeof sut.field[0]);
```

Comment: no need to make that function; it already exists: `strncpy`, and IIRC, `strcpyn` on some compilers.

Comment: @Will the code for `strncopy` uses `strncpy` internally. The OP is adding functionality to `strncpy` which guarantees that the string is always null-terminated.

Comment: that being the case, then don't use `strncpy` at all, and do it yourself with a simple while loop and copy char by char, remembering to add the null at the end.

Comment: @Will - as easy as it is to get pointers wrong, especially off-by-one errors, you'd suggest to roll your own rather than use the known-and-tested function?

Comment: whatever floats ones boat - I usually initialize my buffers so that they are filled with nulls to begin with, then `strncpy`, giving it one less than the buffer size as the maximum number of characters to copy. there are a number of ways to do it; was merely suggesting another.

Comment: Anything other than explicit NUL termination is *dangerous*, especially when giving advice to beginners.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `sut.field[0]` is indeed `char [MAX_CHARS+1]`.  However, most of the other answers have the type of `"Name, "` wrong - it is actually of type `char [7]` (use `sizeof "Name, "` for an easy demonstration of this).

Nonetheless, you still cannot directly assign a `char [7]` to a `char [MAX_CHARS+1]`.  You cannot even directly assign a `char [7]` to another `char [7]` (*initialisation* is treated differently from *assignment* in this way).

The answer is probably just to use a coyping function - for example, if you are certain that `MAX_CHARS >= 6`, then you can just use `strcpy()`.  If you cannot be sure about the length being correct, then you can use `strncat()` as as truncating string copy:

```
sut.field[0][0] = '\0';
strncat(sut.field[0], "Name, ", MAX_CHARS);
```

(Note that despite the name, `strncpy()` is *not* suitable for this, and in fact is very rarely the desired function at all).

---

It is worth pointing out, however, that you *can* indirectly assign arrays (of the same type) if they are wrapped up inside a `struct`.  This means that the following will work (if you have a C99 compiler):

```
typedef struct { char s[MAX_CHARS+1] } f_string;    /* string for each field */

csv_line sut;
sut.field[0] = (f_string){"Name, "};
```

Comment: +1 for `strncat`. Was reminded that `strncpy` will not terminate if the source is larger than the destination; had forgotten as well that `strncat` *does* terminate the destination buffer with a null. Been working with C++ std::string for too long that I forget some of the nuances of C strings.