# Error converting const char to char in struct?

Tags: c, char, constants

This is a bit written from memory so I apologize if I made a mistake in this posting. I created a struct and wanted to assign a name to it, but I get this error:

> error: incompatible types in assignment of `const char[3]' to`char[15]'

For the life of me I tried to understand what exactly is wrong here, I thought a constant char can still be assigned.

```
# include <stdio.h>
struct type{       
   char name[15];
   int age;          
};

main(){
   struct type foo;
   foo.name = "bar";  //error here
   foo.age=40;
   printf("Name- %s - Age: %d", foo.name, foo.age);
}
```

Comment: What you've written is not C++, why the tag?

Comment: similar question asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/4362801/513660

Comment: @GMan: What OP has written is not C either, since C does not have assignment to arrays...

Comment: @R: You get what I mean.

Comment: By the way, the error message seems incorrect. `"bar"` has type `char [4]`, not `const char [3]`. The `const` could be a result of compiling C with a C++ compiler, but the `[3]` is nonsense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char name[15];` declares *an array*, which is not assignable in C. Use [string copying routines](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strncpy/) to copy the values, or declare `name` as a pointer - `char* name;` (here you'd have to worry about memory pointed to still being valid).

You can *initialize* a struct-type variable as a whole though:

```
struct type foo = { "bar", 40 };
```

Here string literal `"bar"` (four bytes including zero-terminator) will be copied into the `name` member array.

Answer (score 4):

name is a fixed-size static buffer.  You need to use strcpy or similar functions to assign it a string value.  If you change it to be `const char* name` instead, then your code should work as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strcpy` to copy content of strings.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Thor: How in the world is not not an answer? The OP clearly intends to copy a string to the struct member. Just because the new review tool tells you a post is *short* it doesn't mean it's necessarily bad!

Answer (score 0):

He's confusing an initializer with an assignment.

Once the object is created (the "struct type foo;" line), you have to strcpy into "name").

struct type foo;
   foo.name = "bar";  //error here <<= The compiler can only do a pointer assignment at this point, which is not valid.

==============

Don't write this crappy code:

strcpy_s(foo.name, 15, "bar");

The following allows you change the length in one place:

strcpy_s(foo.name, sizeof(foo.name), "bar");